# Increase refresh token lifetime in B2C custom policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am able to retrieve refresh tokens for my custom B2C policies but would like to increase the token lifetime to the max limit or set the sliding window lifetime to No Expiry.

This was able to be done via the Azure Portal B2C settings for Basic policies but is not available in the portal for custom policies.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-token-session-sso#token-lifetimes-configuration

How can I configure this in my policies?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-manage-sso-and-token-configuration).

Specifically add the following in your RP technical profile.

```
<Item Key="token_lifetime_secs">3600</Item>
```

Can look like this (copied from docs)

```
<ClaimsProviders>
   <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Token Issuer</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
         <TechnicalProfile Id="JwtIssuer">
            <Metadata>
               <Item Key="token_lifetime_secs">3600</Item>
               <Item Key="id_token_lifetime_secs">3600</Item>
               <Item Key="refresh_token_lifetime_secs">1209600</Item>
               <Item Key="rolling_refresh_token_lifetime_secs">7776000</Item>
               <Item Key="IssuanceClaimPattern">AuthorityAndTenantGuid</Item>
               <Item Key="AuthenticationContextReferenceClaimPattern">None</Item>
            </Metadata>
         </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
   </ClaimsProvider>
</ClaimsProviders>
```

Comment: What is the maximum value for refresh token lifetime?

Comment: @TamasMolnar The max lifetime for a refresh token is 90 days (inclusive) per Microsoft Documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tokens-overview

Answer (score 0):

What Parakh said is correct but please take note of the banner on [the page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-manage-sso-and-token-configuration) that he linked to which says the following about **SPA apps with PKCE**:

> **Note**
> Single-page applications using the authorization code flow with PKCE always have a refresh token lifetime of 24 hours while mobile apps, desktop apps, and web apps do not experience this limitation. [Learn more about the security implications of refresh tokens in the browser.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-third-party-cookies-spas#security-implications-of-refresh-tokens-in-the-browser)

That means that settings such as the following may not be respected for those apps:

- `refresh_token_lifetime_secs`
- `rolling_refresh_token_lifetime_secs`
- `allow_infinite_rolling_refresh_token`

  - This last one is *never* respected for SPA w/ PKCE

Comment: Is there somewhere we can request them to allow developers to modify this limit? I feel 24 hours is too harsh and degrades the UX a lot. I understand the security implication but not all other identity providers are logging out users.

Comment: I have raised a feature request for handing over the ability to slide and extend refresh_token completing in the developer's hand for SPA. Here's the link to feature request - https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/76984c1f-b0e4-ed11-a81c-000d3a7a16ce